# Проблема с методом className

Tags: yii2

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть кусок кода

```
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'send-comment', 'class' => 'tested']); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'comment')->widget(CKEditor::className(),[
        'editorOptions' => [
            'preset' => 'full', //разработанны стандартные настройки basic, standard, full данную возможность не обязательно использовать
            'inline' => false, //по умолчанию false
    ],
    ]); ?>
```

Но className() - перечёркнуто , при наведение на неё, PHPstrom говорит такую ошибку "Method className is deprecated".

Как это исправить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В новой версии yii2 убрали этот метод. Используйте вместо него просто статическое свойство class. То есть `CKEditor::class`. Весь список изменений можно найти здесь: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.14/framework/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

`className()` считается устаревшим и не рекомендуется к использованию (хотя продолжает работать как и раньше). В каком-то из обновлений этот метод будет удален и при обновлении приложения (если этот метод до сих пор будет использоваться в приложении) возникнут ошибки. Вместо этого рекомендуется использовать `CKEditor::class`.